Themes admin page lists a theme, but it fails to delete and is not present on disk
When I go to the appearance admin page, it shows a whole bunch of themes that I don't need (for example the stock "Twenty Fifteen" theme), but when I go to delete them, it fails, saying:

Deletion failed: The requested theme does not exist.

If I look in my wp-content/themes folder, I can see that the theme is indeed not there.
Why are these themes listed, and how can I remove them?
I've seen many questions asking about the opposite problem, but not this way around!

Well this is silly!
It turns out that someone had moved these themes into a folder called "unused", which I didn't look in. It appears that WP finds themes stored in subfolders, but doesn't adjust paths to match when it comes to deleting them.
This is a WordPress bug.
